# Jenkins and AWS interaction help needed

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins

I am trying to get jenkins to automatically build a new ec2 instance from a previous snapshot. So essentially I want Jenkins to be able to create a new volume from my snapshot and then attach this volume to an instance and boot it up. 
Is this possible ?? Spent days scouring all the CI pages but cannot piece it together to do what I want

Comment: Of course, you can do that, you need to learn a little about [AWS Command Line Interface (CLI)](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/)

Answer (score 0):

The way I've been doing it is to first create a volume from a snapshot, then you create an instance, and then you attach that volume to the instance. Like so:

```
# Create a volume from a snapshot:
def createVolume(snapshot_id=None, volume_type=None, volume_size=None, region=None, az=None):
    say('Creating volume...', banner="*")
    snapshot_arg = ' --snapshot-id {}'.format(snapshot_id)
    if snapshot_id is None:
        snapshot_arg = ''

    volume_size = '' if volume_size is None else ' --size ' + volume_size
    cmd = 'aws ec2 create-volume --region ' + region + \
          ' --availability-zone ' + az + ' ' + \
          snapshot_arg + \
          ' --volume-type ' + volume_type + volume_size
    output, returncode = run(cmd, hide_command=g_hide_command, debug=g_args.debug)
    volume_id = json.loads(output)['VolumeId']
    size = json.loads(output)['Size']
    while True:
        cmd = 'aws ec2 describe-volumes --volume-ids ' + str(volume_id)
        output, returncode = run(cmd, hide_command=g_hide_command, debug=g_args.debug)
        state = json.loads(output)['Volumes'][0]['State']
        if state == 'available':
            say('Volume has been created: ' + str(volume_id))
            break
        else:
            say('Current State: ' + str(state))
            time.sleep(15)
    cmd = 'aws ec2 create-tags --resources ' + str(volume_id) + ' --tags Key=Name,Value=jenkins-volume'
    output, returncode = run(cmd, hide_command=g_hide_command, debug=g_args.debug)
    return volume_id, size
```

And once the new volume is created, you can create the instance and attach that volume to the instance:

```
new_instance = createInstance(ami_id=g_args.ami_id,
                              instance_type=g_args.instance_type,
                              target_env=g_args.target_env,
                              ssh_user=g_args.ssh_user,
                              id_rsa=g_args.id_rsa,
                              key_name='jenkins.cloud',
                              tags_dict=tags,
                              security_group_ids=g_env_map[g_args.target_env]['jenkins-sg'],
                              instance_profile=instance_profile,
                              subnet_id=subnet_id,
                              debug=g_args.debug)

# Attach volume to this instance (we reset the new_instance variable because the EBS vol has been attached):
new_instance = attacheVolume(volume_id=volume_id, instance_id=str(new_instance['InstanceId']), region=g_env_map[g_args.target_env]['region'])
```

I didn't put the contents of various functions like createInstance and attachVolume (and "say" and "run"), but you get the gist.